# How can I copy a screenshot of my Bing Maps image to the Clipboard in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot, bing-maps

In my winforms app, I want to allow the user to copy a screenshot of the Bing Maps component to the clipboard (at least).

I found the following code, from [here](https://blogs.bing.com/Developers-Blog/2014-05/How-to-Save-and-Share-Map-Screenshots-in-Windows-Store-Apps-(-NET)), which goes above and beyond that, but it doesn't compile for me.

```
SaveScreenshot(this.userControl11.myMap, "MapScreenshot.png"); // code in menu item click handler

private async void SaveScreenshot(FrameworkElement captureSource, string suggestedName)
{
    //Create a FileSavePicker.
    var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker()
    {
        DefaultFileExtension = ".png",
        SuggestedFileName = suggestedName,
        SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary
    };

    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".png", new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { ".png" });

    //Prompt the user to select a file.
    var saveFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

    //Verify the user selected a file.
    if (saveFile != null)
    {                
        using (var fileStream = await saveFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            //Capture the screenshot and save it to the file stream.
            await ScreenshotToStreamAsync(captureSource, fileStream);
        }
    }
}

private async Task ScreenshotToStreamAsync(FrameworkElement element, IRandomAccessStream stream)
{
    var renderTargetBitmap = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(element);

    var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

    var dpi = Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;

    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(
        BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
        (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
        (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
        dpi,
        dpi,
        pixelBuffer.ToArray());

    await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```

The compile-time err msgs I get is about IRandomAccessStream:

```
1>C:\Users\bclay\source\repos\MyMaps\MyMaps\Form1.cs(394,78,394,97): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IRandomAccessStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

So I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.irandomaccessstream?view=winrt-19041), which indicates the "using" I need is using Windows.Storage.Streams;

...but when I add that, I am told that the "Windows" namespace cannot be found:

```
1>C:\Users\bclay\source\repos\MyMaps\MyMaps\Form1.cs(8,7,8,14): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Windows' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What do I need to do/change/add to get this to work on Winforms? Or is a totally different approach needed in my case?

Comment: The `Windows.Storage.Streams` namespace is available to UWP apps. So are the Pickers etc. You can use `RenderTargetBitmap` to render the DrawingVisual of your Map object, adding an internal method to the UserControl (which probably uses the Bing Map Control for WPF, IIRC there isn't one for WinForms) and return a BitmapSource or convert it to Bitmap. BTW, the ElementHost has a `DrawToBitmap` method. Maybe it can render the content (I've never used it with a Bing Map, so I don't know whether it will do anything or anything good).

Comment: Yes, I am using the WPF Bing Map control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

As an easy (but definitely not a perfect) option, you can use [Graphics.FromScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to copy a piece of screen to the graphics object:

```
var r = elementHost1.ClientRectangle;
using (var img = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height))
{
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(img))
    {
        var sr = elementHost1.RectangleToScreen(r);
        g.CopyFromScreen(sr.Location, System.Drawing.Point.Empty, sr.Size);
    }
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetImage(img);
}
```

Another option is using [RenderTargetBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and [PngBitmapEncoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to export it to image like this:

```
public System.Drawing.Image DrawToImage(
    System.Windows.Controls.Control target)
{
    var rtb = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)(target.ActualWidth), (int)(target.ActualHeight),
            96, 96, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    rtb.Render(target);
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder encoder =
        new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
    var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    encoder.Save(ms);
    return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Then you can set it into the clipboard:

```
using (var image = DrawToImage(userControl11.myMap))
    System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetImage(image);
```

Or save it to a file:

```
using (var image = DrawToImage(userControl11.myMap))
    image.Save(@"c:\test\map.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Perfect! I used the second option and pasting it into the clipboard. Thanks!